# What's the definition of LDS the genre?

Tags: genre-characteristics

Spotify included "LDS" among my Top 5 genres. But what exactly is "LDS"?
I googled around and it only told me something about Mormons...

Comment: @Aaron Sure, as it stands it's probably musicfans-appropriate. I'm intrigued, though, and Dr_Hope, I'd love to see this edited into a more in-depth question by asking more about the *nature* of such a genre. I too turned up only Mormon ("Latter Day Saints") results and wondered how that could possibly be a "genre", since my (outsider) perception of Mormon culture is that it's not markedly distinct from the rest of American Evangelical contemporary Christian aesthetics. But then there are [articles like this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mormon_music), suggesting that...

Comment: ... what started as sociological reasons for drawing a distinction evolved actual musical markers. I'm curious what they might be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The LDS genre is exactly as it seems: [music and artists consistent with Mormonism or of interest to Mormons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mormon_music).

A couple of examples:

There is an organization called "Latter-day Saint Musicians" that has a Spotify account ...

> to provide a library of good music that people can listen to and discover without being concerned about songs that have questionable lyrics. At the same time, the playlists that have been created will help introduce listeners to Mormon artists and their music. ([SOURCE](https://latterdaysaintmusicians.com/music-news/mormon-musics-new-spotify-account))

There is also a channel "[The Sound of LDS](https://open.spotify.com/playlist/6PA6TCSmljI69KJ8Co6tVd)" that is similarly geared toward Mormon listeners and artists.

Comment: oh dear... didn't know that I was lured by their music